# Silverlight 4 - related table datagrid display sorting

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I am using the sample code from http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#QueryRelatedRecords to display related data into a data grid. In my data I need the table to be sorted by the year (an attribute in my related table named "_year"). I am not sure how to accomplish this - in the xaml or c#. Below is my current code:

xaml:

```
               <basics:TabControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox">
                <basics:TabItem x:Name="DataTab" Header="Data">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <slData:DataGrid x:Name="RelatedRowsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="All" 
                     BorderThickness="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="4,0,2,6" Height="127" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <slData:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <slData:DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="False"  Binding="{Binding Attributes[loc_id]}" Header="Location ID" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                <slData:DataGridTextColumn  CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Attributes[_year]}" Header="Year"/>
                                <slData:DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding Attributes[adt]}" Header="ADT"/>
                            </slData:DataGrid.Columns>
                        </slData:DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </basics:TabItem>
                <basics:TabItem x:Name="ChartTab" Header="Chart">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <toolkit:Chart x:Name="MyChart2" Title="{Binding [PAGsde.DBO.TrafficCountNetwork.loc_id]}" 
                           esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTipHideDelay="0:0:3" Background="LightGray"  
                           LegendStyle="{StaticResource BlankLegendStyle}" TitleStyle="{StaticResource SmallTitleStyle}">
                            <toolkit:Chart.Series>
                                <toolkit:ColumnSeries Title="ADT" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Attributes[_year]}" 
                                          DependentValueBinding="{Binding Attributes[adt]}">
                                </toolkit:ColumnSeries>
                            </toolkit:Chart.Series>
                        </toolkit:Chart>
                    </Grid>
                </basics:TabItem>
            </basics:TabControl>
```

C#:

```
 private void SelectedRoadsTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (e.OldValue != null)
    {
        Graphic g = e.OldValue as Graphic;
        g.UnSelect();
        g.SetZIndex(0);
    }

    if (e.NewValue != null)
    {
        Graphic g = e.NewValue as Graphic;
        g.Select();
        g.SetZIndex(1);

        //Relationship query
        RelationshipParameter relationshipParameters = new RelationshipParameter()
        {
            ObjectIds = new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(g.Attributes[SelectedRoadsTreeView.Tag as string]) },
            OutFields = new string[] { "loc_id, count_id, _year, adt" },
            RelationshipId = 0,
            OutSpatialReference = Map.SpatialReference
        };

        queryTask.ExecuteRelationshipQueryAsync(relationshipParameters);

        MyChart2.Title = g.Attributes["TrafficCounts.COUNTUSER.%segment_master._street"];
    }
}
void QueryTask_ExecuteRelationshipQueryCompleted(object sender, RelationshipEventArgs e)
{
    RelationshipResult pr = e.Result;
    if (pr.RelatedRecordsGroup.Count == 0)
    {
        RelatedRowsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var pair in pr.RelatedRecordsGroup)
        {
            RelatedRowsDataGrid.ItemsSource = pair.Value;
            //?.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Attributes[_year]", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            ((ColumnSeries)MyChart2.Series[0]).ItemsSource = pair.Value;    //new KeyValuePair<int, int>[] { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2005, 1200) };
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This Code Should Help You May Be

```
 bool SortDateAsc = true;
    private void Date_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SortDateAsc)
        {
            ObservableCollection<InvoicesDTO> a = new ObservableCollection<InvoicesDTO>(((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).MainInvoiceList.OrderBy(oc => oc.FC_AGE));
            ((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).MainInvoiceList = a;
            InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = ((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).MainInvoiceList.ToList();
            SortDateAsc = false;
            ((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).RefreshSelctedInvoice();
        }
        else
        {
            ObservableCollection<InvoicesDTO> a = new ObservableCollection<InvoicesDTO>(((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).MainInvoiceList.OrderByDescending(oc => oc.FC_AGE));
            ((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).MainInvoiceList = a;
            InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = ((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).MainInvoiceList.ToList();
            SortDateAsc = true;
            ((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).RefreshSelctedInvoice();
        }

    }
```